# No debug output obtained from runnng NUnit test on Visual Studio Express 2013

Tags: .net, debugging, express, nunit, output

I am trying to debug NUnit tests on VS Express 2013. I do not see any debug prints though. I looked up a number of posts on stackoverflow and other websites but nothing has helped.

1. I disabled module load / unload on the output window and enabled only output text
2. I attached nunitagent to the debug process on VS since I am using .NET 4.0

Has anyone else been able to run this successfully?